# Inspect Android project information in GitHub

Tags: android, github, gitlab

Some GitHub users who are not familiar or unknowingly forget to remove sensitive info. from their code once they push the project to GitHub. Such as Permissions used, APIs token, and user conditionals. Is there a way/tool I can track each project which has such info. to make a statical analysis result?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/kootenpv/gittyleaks

Comment: @GoodDeeds thanks a lot, you gave a useful link, I will deep into - as I'm still a beginner for GitHub.